# Hash Function with Order Preserving

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hash

Is there any hash function with uniq hash code (like MD5) with order preserving?

NOTE:
i don't care about security, i need it for sorting, i have lot of chunks with (~1MB size) and i want to sort them, of course i can use index sort but i want to reduce time of compare

Theoreticaly:
if i have 1'000'000 chunks with 1MB size (1'048'576 byte) and all of them have difference in last 10 bytes then time of compare of one chunk to other will be O(n-10) and if i will use QuictSort (which make ~(n*log2(n)) compares) then total time of compare will be n*log2(n)*(k-10) (where k is chunk size)
1'000'000 * 20 * (1'048'576 - 10)

that's why i want to generate order preserved hash codes  with fixed size (for example 16 bytes) once then sort chunks and save result (for example: in file)

Comment: What are you hoping to do with this hash function?

Comment: the only purpose for hashing is to shuffle, now you want to preserve the order...

Comment: i feel this is a XY problem. op is misleading us.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

CHM (Z.J. Czech, G. Havas, and B.S. Majewski) is an algorithm which generates a minimal perfect hash that preserves ordering (e.g. if A < B, then h(A) < h(B)). It uses approximately 8 bytes of storage per key.

See: http://cmph.sourceforge.net/chm.html

Comment: CHM requires keys to be known in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In general case, such a function is impossible unless the size of the hash is at least the size of the object.

The argument is trivial: if there are N objects but M < N hash values, by [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), two different objects are mapped to one hash value, and so their order is not preserved.

If however we have additional properties of the objects guaranteed or the requirements relaxed, a custom or probabilistic solution may become possible.

Comment: yes i know that but 16 bytes (128 bits) have very large space and if i will have two same Hash Codes in range 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 ...
it's OK for me :)

Comment: @Simon: To _guarantee_ that `hash(A) <= hash(B)` for `A < B`, you can use the first 16 bytes of objects as the hash. How likely are these 16 bytes to be equal, anyway, for your particular data set? You may be trying to solve a non-problem here.

Comment: Gassa, Thanks for your replay
but as i mentioned above

Theoretically: there can be 1'000'0000 chunks with size 1MB (each), which differs from each other only by last 10 bytes

Comment: True in the general case it is impossible, but then so is a collisionless hash and we don't worry about that in practice because the probability of a collision is negligible. A reasonable interpretation of the original question would be for a hash that strictly preserves order *as long as there is no collision*.

Answer (score 4):

According to NIST (I'm no expert) a Pearson hash can be order-preserving. The hash uses an auxiliary table. Such a table can (in theory) be constructed such that the resulting hash is order preserving.

It doesn't meet your full requirements though, because it doesn't reduce the size as you would like. I'm posting this in case other people are looking for a solution.

Some pointers:

- The NIST page: http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/pearsonshash.html
- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing
- The original Pearson Hash paper: http://cs.mwsu.edu/~griffin/courses/2133/downloads/Spring11/p677-pearson.pdf

Comment: @l-blanc I don't think that a Pearson can easily be manipulated in the way you describe.  The auxiliary table is meant to be entirely random. If you read Pearson's paper, you'll see that his attempts in rigging the table for perfect hashing of only 31 words succeeds after extensive trial and error.  And the resultant hash is only 1 byte long. To expand this to the general case  for > 8 bit output, I think would be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting an array of `N` strings each of length `K` can be done in just `O (NK)` or `O (N^2 + NK)` character comparisons.

For example, construct a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Or do a kind of insertion sort.  Construct the set of sorted strings `S` by adding strings to it one by one.  For each new string `P`, traverse it, maintaining the (non-decreasing) index of the greatest string `Q` in `S` such that `Q <= P`.  When the string `P` ends, insert it into `S` just after `Q`. Each of the `O(N)` insertions can be done in `O(N+K)` operations: `O(N)` times increasing the index distributed into `K`.

---

When you have indices of the strings in sorted order, just use them for your purposes instead of the "hashes" you want.

Answer (score 2):

Lets construct such a function from the requirements:

1. You want a function that outputs a 16 byte hash. So you will have collisions. You can't preserve perfect order and you don't want to. Best you can do is:

   H(x) < H(y) => x < y

   H(x) > H(y) => x > y

Values close to each other will have the same hash.

2. For each x there is an i_x > 0 so that `H(x) = H(x + i_x) < H(x + i_x + 1)`. (Except for the end where `x + i_x + 1` would overflow your 1MB chunks.)

Extending that you get: `H(x) < H(x + i_x + n)` for any `n > 0`.

Same argument works for j_x > 0 in the other direction. Combine them and you get:

```
H(x - j_x) == H(x - j_x + 1) == ... == H(x + i_x - 1) == H(x + i_x)
```

Or in other words for each hash value there is a single segment [a, b] mapping to the same value. No value outside this segment can have the same hash value or the ordering would be violated.

Your hash function can then be described by the segments you choose:

Let a_i be 1MB chunks with `0 <= i < 256^16` and `a_i <= a_i+1`. Then

```
H(x) = i where a_i <= x < a_i+1
```

3. You want an more of less uniform distribution of hash values. Otherwise one would get far more collisions than another and you would spend all the time doing a full compare when that value is hit. So all the segments [a, b] should be about the same size.

The only way to have exact the same size for each segment is to have

```
a_i = i * 2 ^ (1MB - 16)
```

or in other words: H(x) = first 16 bytes of x.

Any other order preserving hash function with a 16 byte output would be less efficient for a random set of input blocks.

And yes, if all but the last few bits of each input block are the same then every test will be a collision. That's a worst case scenario that always exists. If you know your inputs aren't uniformly random then you can adjust the size of each segment to have the same probability to be hit. But that requires knowledge of likely inputs.

Note: If you really want to sort 1'000'000 1MB chunks where you fear such a worst case then you can use bucket sort, resulting in 1,000,000 * 1'048'576 (byte) compares every time. Half of that if you compare 16 bit values at a time, which still has a reasonable number of buckets (65536).

Answer (score -3):

In theory there is no such thing. If you want, you can create a composed hash:

> index:md5

I think this will resolve your needs.

Comment: no... because it should be searchable... for example: if i use insex:md5(n) then i will not be able to search data using just md5(n)

Comment: and also i want order preserved hash because i want to be able to search data with some conditions, for example: if i want to iterate data which is more then N then i can to search and iterate data by hash codes which is more then hash(N)